# How do i generate a random number in c++ between 1 and 16?

Tags: c++

I don't know how to generate a random number between 1 and 16 in c++, i only know the `int random = rand() % 100` method to generate a number between 0-99. can someone help me out please?

Comment: What do you think `rand() % 100` does?

Comment: @DeiDei It generates a number between 0-99? As i said above?

Comment: Yeah, why does it do that?

Comment: 99 relates to 100 like 16 relates to 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea as 100

```
int r = rand() % 17;
```